# NSURLSession .waitsForConnectivity flag ignored when DataTask being run on OperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsurlsession, operation

I have a handwritten class MyURLRequest, that implements Operation. Inside it creates URLSession, configures it

```
public init(shouldWaitForConnectivity: Bool, timeoutForResource: Double?) {
    baseUrl = URL(string: Self.relevantServerUrl + "api/")
    self.shouldWaitForConnectivity = shouldWaitForConnectivity
    self.timeoutForResource = timeoutForResource
    super.init()
    localURLSession = URLSession(configuration: localConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

}

```
public var localConfig: URLSessionConfiguration {
    let res = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    res.allowsCellularAccess = true
    if let shouldWaitForConnectivity = shouldWaitForConnectivity {
        res.waitsForConnectivity = shouldWaitForConnectivity
        if let timeoutForResource = timeoutForResource {
            res.timeoutIntervalForResource = timeoutForResource
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

creates URLRequest, dataTask, and then being run on OperationQueue. Operation's methods looks like this

```
override open func start() {
    if isCancelled {
        isFinished = true
        return
    }
    
    startDate = Date()
    sessionTask?.resume()
    localURLSession.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}

override open func cancel() {
    super.cancel()
    sessionTask?.cancel()
}
```

MyURLRequest also implements `URLSessionDataDelegate` and `URLSessionTaskDelegate` and the being delegate for it's own URLSession.

There is a problem with `waitsForConnectivity` NSURLSessionConfiguration's flag. In constructor I set it to true, but this flag is being ignored. In runtime, when network is turned off, request finishes immediately with error -1009. URLSessionTaskDelegate's method **urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)** is triggered immediately. **func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, taskIsWaitingForConnectivity task: URLSessionTask)** not being called at all.

The reason definitely not is that flag waitsForConnectivity wasn't correctly set: I've checked config in task received by **urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)**, and waitsForConnectivity == true.

I also tried to make request without operation queue, and that went fine - behaved such as expected. Maybe have something to do with OperationQueue. Would appreciate your help!

**UPDATE:**
Seems like root of the problem is that Operation being released too early (when request not complete yet). I've tried to synchronise them using DispatchGroup():

```
override open func start() {
    if isCancelled {
        isFinished = true
        return
    }
    startDate = Date()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    sessionTask?.resume()
    dispatchGroup.wait()

    localURLSession.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

where .leave() is called in URLSessionDelegate's methods. Nothing changed, still not waiting for connectivity.

**UPDATE:**
Here's the error I get in **didCompleteWithError:**

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc319112de0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <6388AD46-8497-40DF-8768-44FEBB84A8EC>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <6388AD46-8497-40DF-8768-44FEBB84A8EC>.<1>",
    "LocalDataTask <26BCBD73-FC8B-4A48-8EA2-1172ABB8093C>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is rooted in your use of `finishTasksAndInvalidate`. It looks like you are depending on that method synchronously waiting for all pending tasks to complete, but according to the documentation that isn't how it works.

Here's a more in-depth explanation of what I think is happening. By default an `Operation` is considered complete as soon as the `start` method returns. This is definitely **not** what you need, as the task has to be completed asynchronously. `Operation` is **not** capable of supporting this behavior out of the box.

Your `start` returns immediately, long before the session has any time to complete the task you have started. Then, with the operation complete, the queue removes it. This often ends up being the only owner of that instance. If that's true, it kicks off the operation deinit process, which ends up releasing the `URLSession`. At **that** point, the session looks like it might do some clean up and terminate any outstanding tasks, forwarding some calls to its delegate. I wasn't sure if URLSession does this, but based on what you are seeing, it sounds like it may.

To achieve what you want, I think you'll need to restructure your `NSOperation` subclass to be fully asynchronous and to only complete when the started task is done.

Building out a fully thread-safe async `NSOperation` subclass is a real pain. In case this isn't something you've tackled before, you can check out an implementation here: https://github.com/ChimeHQ/OperationPlus

Comment: I also thought that's the case, but commenting that line done nothing :(

Comment: Yes, that exactly matches what I would expect. The problem is that your NSOperation lifecycle isn't tied to sessionTask. So, the operation terminates early, deallocates the session and prematurely ends all tasks. (assuming that localURLSession is owned by the operation)

Comment: But if Operation deallocates and then session is deallocated, how is delegate method triggered? Operation object serves as delegate for session

Comment: Good question! Why not set a breakpoint in your delegate method and find out?

Comment: I tried it! Delegate method "withError" worked BEFORE deinit of operation

Comment: So that means when request fails with error, Operation still does exist

Comment: Yes, we knew it would be called before it was deinited. I wanted to know what was going on in the stack at the time. I've added some clarification to the answer. So far, everything we've seen still supports the `Operation` lifecycle not matching your session task. But, I cannot see all of your code, especially the rest of the operation subclass implementation, which is critical here.

Comment: I've tried to move URLSession outside of Operation, and to assign outer delegate to URLSession. In this case there isn't any dependance on existence of Operation anymore. But bad behavior continues - URLSession still ignores .waitsForConnectivity flag :( May the reason be that URLSessionDataTask instance still stored inside of Operation?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no arrangement that will work with a stock Operation. You need to redo how your Operation defines that it is done, or use a library to do that work for you.

Comment: thank you very much. Please check the update.

Comment: Ah yes! Using a group as a lock to make the async task sync is one way. Maybe you'd like to also post the error returned when leave is called? At this point, I think in theory you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: I've posted the error, please check